# Mapstruct: How to merge two fields into one

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

Using the MapStruct framework, how do you map multiple fields into a single one (based on custom logic) while still mapping the other fields one to one?

Here is a simple example to illustrate what I mean:

```java
public class Source {
    private String firstname;               
    private String surname;  
    // other fields eg:
    private String address; 
    private int age;
    private int favoriteNumber;
}
```

```java
public class Target {
    private String fullname; // Sould be firstname + surname
    // other fields eg:
    private String address; 
    private int age;
    private int favoriteNumber;
}
```

I know it's possible using expressions:

```java
@Mapping(target = "fullname", expression = "java(el.getFirstname() + el.getSurname())")
```

But in my special use case, not depicted in this example, I need to use some external library for the merging/mapping of the two fields, which isn't feasible with expressions.

Is there a way to achieve merging two fields without expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @AfterMapping annotation

https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappings-with-before-and-after

You would like to replace your interface with abstract class and then

```
    @AfterMapping
    void customMapping(@MappingTarget Target target, Source source) {
        // any custom logic
    }
```

Comment: You don't have to make your mapper and a stranger class. You can also have a default method in an interface

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to add a [custom mapping method](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#adding-custom-methods) from the `Source` object to the merged value, and then declare the source for the merged field to be the whole source object:

```java
interface CustomMappingMethodMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "fullname", source = ".")
    Target map(Source source);

    default String getFullName(Source s) {
        return s.getFirstname() + " " + s.getSurname();
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach is bad, because if there are other fields that require custom mapping, the same method will be invoked for all of them. You need to use `qualifiedBy` or `qualifiedByName`

Comment: @MarcusVoltolim Not correct. In this example, only the "fullname" property will use the custom mapping method, since none of the other properties will be mapped using the whole source object (unless it's a recursive object that contains a `Source`).  Everything else will use the standard mapping based on property names.  You certainly could add a `qualifiedBy*` to make it explicit or if a second `String` property later gets added that needs the full source object to map it.

Comment: I meant exactly this, if there is another field that receives the source and returns String, everyone will use the same method, thus creating the need for qualifiedBy...

Comment: @MarcusVoltolim My point was that `qualifiedBy` or `qualifiedByName` are not needed in this specific example because there are no other properties that receives the source and returns the `String` (with the unlikely edge case that `Source` contains a property of type `Source` that maps to `String`).  Saying that they're needed is inaccurate in this specific example.  And I personally would be cautious about adding unnecessary qualifications, because it might clutter things up with mapping configurations that aren't actually used in practice, and make the actually necessary stuff less obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You claim that calling an external library in an expression isn't feasible.  This may not be true, depending on the nature of the library you're calling and the frameworks being used.

### Static method

If the method being called is a static method on a class, it can be called directly within the [`expression`](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Mapping.html#expression--) annotation element of `@Mapping`.  To avoid having to fully qualify the class being called, the [`imports`](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Mapper.html#imports--) element of `@Mapper` can be used.

```java
@Mapper(imports = ExternalLibrary.class)
public interface SourceToTargetMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "fullname",
            expression = "java(ExternalLibrary.toFullName(s.getFirstname(), s.getSurname()))")
    Target map(Source s);
}
```

### Spring Framework bean

If the library method is a method on a [Spring](https://spring.io) bean, the mapper can be made into a bean using the Spring component model, and the Spring bean containing the library method can be injected into the mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public static abstract class SourceToTargetMapper {
    @Autowired
    ExternalLibrary externalLibrary;

    @Mapping(target = "fullname",
            expression = "java(externalLibrary.toFullName(s.getFirstname(), s.getSurname()))")
    abstract Target map(Source s);
}
```

To use this mapper, inject it as a Spring bean, and call the mapping method on the bean:

```java
@Component
public class Example {
  @Autowired
  private SourceToTargetMapper mapper;

  public void demonstrate(Source s) {
    System.out.println(mapper.map(s));
  }
}
```

I haven't tested it myself, but I imagine this injection approach would work with the other [component models](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#using-dependency-injection) supported by MapStruct (`cdi` & `jsr330`).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to compose 2 basic fields into am Wrapped Object. Here's how I did id

```
 @Mapping(source = "quantity", target = "energyQuantity.quantity")
 @Mapping(source = "quantityUnit", target = "energyQuantity.energyQuantityUnit", qualifiedByName = "tradeSearchEnergyQuantityUnitToEnergyQuantityUnit")
    Trade tradeSearchToDomainDTO(api.client.generated.model.Trade trade);
```

where `energyQuantity` is a Wrapper class for the 2 fields